# phpMyAdmin keeps throwing error #1064

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

Here's the error warning I get when executing my query:

[image: error and query]

My database structure:

[image: db structure]

Can anyone help me find the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHARACTER` is a [reserved MySQL keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html), try putting it in quotes:

```
SELECT name FROM `CHARACTER`
```